# Can static member class assess the enclosing class's members in Java?

Tags: java

I have been reading the book ,when I read the item 22:Favor static member classes over nonstatic,I was confused about this opinion,that static member class can access the enclosing class's members? 
[image]

Comment: Code is worth 1024 words: Show us a coded example of what you want (and while you're at it, you know, try to compile it and see what happens).

Comment: Also, don't quote using images. Quote using text and a blockquote tag. It's not like the above is long or hard to type. Be sure to give attribution.

Comment: What is the doubt? Where is the confusion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can static member class assess the enclosing class's members in Java?

Yes, they can. This is trivial to check:

```
public class Example {
    private static String foo = "foo";

    private String bar;

    private Example() {
        this.bar = "bar";
    }

    static class Inner {
        static void check() {
            System.out.println(foo);
            System.out.println(new Example().bar);
        }
    }

    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        Inner.check();
    }
}
```

The above compiles, and outputs "foo" and then "bar", showing that:

- `Inner` has access to the private static field `foo`.
- `Inner` has access to the private `Example` constructor.
- `Inner` has access to the private instance field `bar`.

The *reason* they have access is that the nested class is a member of the enclosing class (see [JLS§8.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3), just like any other member (for instance, a member function of the enclosing class), so it has access to the private parts of the enclosing class just like a method member of the enclosing class does.

Unlike *inner classes* (non-`static` member classes), the class has no implicit link to an enclosing *instance* of the enclosing class (no implicit link to a `this`). So to access instance-specific fields or methods, it has to create an instance (as above when we wanted to access `bar`), as otherwise it has no instance to use.